# Programmatically change View properies Android

Tags: android, android-layout

In general, I'm trying to understand if it's possible in Android to arbitrarily change the properties of a view programmatically.

I understand that there are many properties that can be changed via methods (e.g. TextView.setBackgroundColor() among many others) but there aren't methods for every possible property.

Specifically, I'm interested in instantiating a custom View and then changing the layout_weight. I'm interested in learning how to do this, but in general I want to know how I'm supposed to create a custom View if I can't change it's properties programmatically. I understand I can change all its properties in xml (including custom xml properties) but I want to be able to instantiate the view at run-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`layout_` attributes are actually slightly different than most other things as explained in [this pro-tip](https://plus.google.com/+IanLake/posts/Hepj6KynZD5): they're instructions to the **parent ViewGroup** and are stored in their `LayoutParams`.

For example, `layout_weight` in a `LinearLayout` would be found in [LinearLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#weight). This means you can change them by doing

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = 
    (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) yourCustomView.getLayoutParams();
// Set the weight however you like
params.weight = 4.0f;
```

Creating the view allows you to do this as well:

```
LinearLayout parentLayout = ...;
YourCustomView yourCustomView = ...;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, // width
    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, // height
    1.0f); // weight
parentLayout.addView(yourCustomView, params);
```

Comment: Thanks. So in general, can I change properties by accessing the properties of the LayoutParams object?

Comment: @Bob - yes, generally `layout_` attributes will have associated public variables or methods associated with them.

Comment: btw, that pro-tip you linked to was extremely helpful in understanding how these things work generally. thanks!